# In special relativity, is it true that mass is conserved and energy is conserved?

Tags: special-relativity, conservation-laws, mass-energy

If so, it would seem to follow that a photon has mass, because an atom that emits a photon loses mass. If the photon has no mass, then the total mass will be less and mass will not have been conserved.

So one might conclude that a photon has mass, but most physicists say that it has no mass. They call it a "massless particle". For example, this Wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon) says, "Current commonly accepted physical theories imply or assume the photon to be strictly massless. If the photon is not a strictly massless particle, it would not move at the exact speed of light, c, in vacuum. Its speed would be lower and depend on its frequency. Relativity would be unaffected by this; the so-called speed of light, c, would then not be the actual speed at which light moves, but a constant of nature which is the upper bound on speed that any object could theoretically attain in spacetime.[33] Thus, it would still be the speed of spacetime ripples (gravitational waves and gravitons), but it would not be the speed of photons."

I find it interesting that the phrase "massless particle" is used over and over, as if the author is unsure whether that means that a photon has no mass, but that aside it is unambiguous.

Comment: Question is ok in my opinion so I upvoted it and gave an answer. (I guess the reason for previous downvotes was that the question does not show much evidence of research. But hey I felt like answering.)

Answer (score 4):

I use the term "mass" to refer to rest mass. Rest mass is not conserved. Energy is conserved.

Here is an example: an object of rest mass $M$ is initially at rest, then it splits into two pieces of rest mass $m$ each. They move off at speed $v$ in opposite directions.

In this example the total energy in the initial situation is
$$
E_i = M c^2
$$
The total energy in the final situation is
$$
E_f = 2 \gamma m c^2
$$
where
$$
\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2}}
$$
Energy is conserved, so
$$
E_f = E_i .
$$
It follows that
$$
2 \gamma m = M
$$
and therefore
$$ 
m = \frac{M}{2 \gamma}.
$$
But for $v \ne 0$ we always get $\gamma > 1$. Therefore
$$
m < \frac{M}{2}
$$
So the total rest mass at the end, $2m$, is less than the initial rest mass, $M$. So rest mass is not conserved.

The example where an atom emits a photon is similar. The atom loses energy, and in consequence its final rest mass is reduced. The energy is carried away by the photon, and a photon does not have any rest mass. So the total amount of rest mass at the end is less than at the beginning. This is another example of the fact that rest mass is not a conserved quantity in physics.

*A comment on zero rest mass*. It can seem odd to say that a photon has zero rest mass. If you want to know precisely what we mean when we say that, then just focus on the momentum and energy of the photon. The precise statement is that the quantity $E^2 - p^2 c^2 = 0$ for a photon, whereas for a massive particle this quantity would be $m^2 c^4$.

*A comment on adding up rest mass.*
Forming a sum of rest masses is rarely of interest. Consider a gas of particles, for example. Say the $i$'th particle has rest mass $m$ and speed $v_i$. Then the total energy of the gas is
$$
E = \sum_i \gamma_i m c^2 = \sum_i \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v_i^2/c^2}}m c^2,
$$
and assuming that the quantities are in the rest frame of the gas, then the rest mass of the system as a whole is this energy divided by $c^2$:
$$
M = \sum_i \gamma_ i m.
$$
I mention this in order to distinguish between the rest mass of the composite system, i.e. $M$, and the sum of the rest masses of its parts, which is $\sum_i m = N m$ for a gas of $N$ particles. This second sum is rarely of interest to physics.

Comment: +1 for being clear and understandable (even for a layman like me) and seemingly free of errors. I was sure, until about a week ago, that energy and mass the same thing. Note that I don't mean rest mass by "mass": I mean any quantity measured in kilograms. It would have seemed to follow that if the total energy is conserved, the total mass must also be conserved, so why not? Why do you say "mass" if you mean "rest mass"? Why not say "rest mass" like most physicists? Wouldn't it reduce confusion?

Comment: @MatthewChristopherBartsh this is just to let you know that the standard terminology in professional physics when relativity is involved is that "mass" means "rest mass"

Comment: What about when relativity is not involved?

Answer (score 3):

In modern physics mass is the quantity $m$ given by $$m^2 c^2 = E^2/c^2 - p^2$$ which reduces to the famous $E = mc^2$ when $p=0$.

Since both the energy $E$ and the momentum $p$ of an isolated system are conserved, the mass is necessarily also conserved. This makes sense because for an isolated system at rest where $E=mc^2$ if the right hand side were not conserved then the left hand side would not be conserved either.

As an example, suppose the system consists of an electron and a positron at rest with respect to each other and isolated from the environment. Each has a mass of $511 \ \mathrm{keV/c^2}$ and no momentum, so the energy of each is also $511 \ \mathrm{keV}$. The energy and momentum of a system is the sum of the energies and momenta of its parts. So the energy of the system is $1022 \ \mathrm{keV}$ and the momentum is zero, which implies that the mass is $1022 \ \mathrm{keV/c^2}$.

Now, suppose that the positron and electron decay into a pair of photons. Each photon is massless and has energy of $511 \ \mathrm{keV}$ so they each have momentum of $511 \ \mathrm{keV c}$. Since the system momentum is conserved their momenta must sum to zero, so they are directed in opposite directions. With a system energy of $1022 \ \mathrm{keV}$ and a system momentum of zero, the system mass is $1022 \ \mathrm{keV/c^2}$.

Thus the mass of an isolated system is conserved, but the mass of a system is not equal to the sum of the masses of its parts. The system of two photons has the same mass as the system of the positron and electron, but each photon individually is massless. The mass of a system is always equal to or greater than the sum of the masses of its parts.

When people claim that mass is not conserved, they are thinking that the mass of a system is equal to the sum of the masses of its parts. This quantity is indeed not conserved, but it is not the mass of the system.

Comment: Say you have three particles of rest mass $m$ each. You leave them moving in some region of space close to one another, but otherwise isolated. When you come back and gather up the particles you find you have three particles each of rest mass $2m$. I think we will agree that this is physically possible.

Comment: @AndrewSteane sure, but neither $3m$ nor $6m$ is the mass of the system of particles, in general. The mass of the system is conserved, but it is not the sum of the masses of the parts

Comment: > *"The mass of a system is always equal to or greater than the sum of the masses of its parts."* Why? Helium atom mass is smaller than sum of masses of alpha and 2 electrons, by about $m_e/6500$.

Comment: @Jan Lalinsky when you take an alpha and two electrons and combine them you do not just get a helium atom, you also get some photons. You cannot neglect those photons. When you include them the above rule follows. The system is the helium atom plus the photons, it has more mass than the sum of the masses of the helium atom and photons (mass is not additive), and the same mass as the original system of an alpha and two electrons (mass is conserved).

Comment: @Dale your statement is correct about system of two photons or two particles repelling each other (having positive interaction energy). But helium atom without photons involved in its creation or the pair electron-positron is a valid system too, and mass of such system is smaller than sum of masses of its constituents.

Comment: @JanLalinsky please ask your question about the helium nucleus as a separate question. This is too involved for a comment. The mass of an individual nucleon in a nucleus is not defined. You cannot assign the parts of the nucleus the masses of the free nucleons.

Comment: @Dale I have no question about this, my comment was to help you realize your statement wasn't generally valid.

Comment: @JanLalinsky it is generally valid. It is simply the triangle inequality in Minkowski spacetime. For vectors in space $|a+b|<|a|+|b|$ and for timelike and null vectors in spacetime $|a+b|>|a|+|b|$. This is a straightforward mathematical theorem, and it always holds in Minkowski spacetime. What is not valid is treating a bound system as the sum of the unbound components. It is too bad that you don’t have a question because you do have this wrong

Comment: @Dale I did not suggest assigning parts of nucleus masses of free nucleons or treating bound system as sum of unbound components. In your triangle inequality theorem, do you include 4-momentum due to EM interaction of positive and negative particle (nucleus and electrons)? If you do, then we get that mass of the system equals sum of masses of all parts. If you do not and only massive particles' momenta are involved, then the theorem can't express total mass and total mass is smaller than sum of masses of the (massive) parts.

Comment: @JanLslinsky all I can tell you is you have this wrong and a correct response doesn’t fit in comments. Please open a question or stop posting misinformation in comments